# The Header overflows about 20px

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, header

I'm working on a school project (restaurant website) based on CMS WordPress but I have a problem with the header, there is some overflow of about 20-19px and I don't know how to fix it.

I can't set a fixed size for the header because it would not work properly for the navigation menu, min-height isn't working either.

Can somebody help me solve this problem? I do not have much time to complete the project, and I still have a lot of work ahead :) The web address is http://restaurant.g6.cz/menu/

[Image shows the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neicv.png)
       
        /*Header*/

```
    header .heading {
      display: block;   
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;    
      background-repeat: no-repeat;}   


    .slider{
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;    
      position: absolute;
    }

      /*Horizontal menu*/

    header nav{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #232323;
        display: table;

    }

    header nav ul{
        background-color: #232323;
        overflow:hidden;
        color:white;
        padding:0px;
        text-align:center;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin:0px;
        transition: max-height 0.4s;
        -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
        -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
        -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
        -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    }

    header nav ul li{
        display:table-cell;
        padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
        border-right: 1px;
        border-right-style:solid;
        border-right-color: #333333;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-weight: bold;


        }

    header nav ul li a{
        font-size: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 20px 16px 20px;
    }

    header nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #171717;
    }

    header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #DDAF4D;
    }

    header nav ul li.current-menu-item {
    background: #171717;
    }

    header nav ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #DDAF4D;
    }


    .menupozmenseni {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #171717;
    text-align:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*padding: 15px 10px;   */
    height: 49px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    display:none;
    background-image:url(obrazky/menu.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 968px) {

    header nav ul{
        max-height: 0px;
    }

    header nav ul li {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    display:block;
    }

    header nav ul li a{
    display:block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 15px 0px 16px 0px;
    }

    .menupozmenseni{
        display:block;

        }

    .skryteprvkymenu{
        max-height: 450px; 
        -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
        -ms-transition: max-height 0.8s;
        -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
        -o-transition: max-height 0.8s;
        }


    }
    </style>





    <header>


        <div class="heading">
                <div class="slider">

      <?php if (is_page($page = 'menu' )){ ?>
      <?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=6]'); ?>

      <?php }   elseif (is_page($page = 'vinny-listek' )){ ?>
      <?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=7]'); ?>

      <?php }else{ ?>
      <?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=5]'); ?>

      <?php } ?>

      </div>
      <div class="site-branding">
                <?php if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) : ?>
                    <div class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <div class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php endif;

                $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
                if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                    <div class="site-description"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
           </div>

      <div class="nadpis">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
      </div>


        </div>

        <nav class="site-nav">

            <?php

            $args = array(
                "theme_location" => "primary"
            );

            ?>

            <?php
                wp_nav_menu($args);
            ?>

    <div class="menupozmenseni"></div>     

        </nav>

    <script>
    $( ".menupozmenseni" ).on( "click", function() {
        $("header nav ul").toggleClass("skryteprvkymenu");
    });
</script>

    </header>
```

Comment: can you please provide your code?

Comment: If you look at your element through the inspector, you have some invisible encoded character after your script tag before you close the header tag, this invisible character is creating the whitespace

Comment: Sweta Parmar: If you really want I can, it seemed better to me to put a link here :)

PhilS: You are right, I can see it now, it is there because the website is responsive, when you resize your browser window, you can see the hidden element. How can I do this differently without empty space? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the inspector, inside your header, you will find this string `"&#65279"`. Check out the screenshot to see for yourself. This is what is causing the extra white-space, delete that and you're good!
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you :) It wasn't visible in PSPad but I downloaded Adobe Dreamweaver Trial and it was visible there like small red point so I deleted this point and it solve my problem, but maybe everybody can solve this problem when save UTF-8 file without BOM :)